# Murder rate by city/state in Germany?

Tags: data-request, crime, germany

I would like to know the murder rate by city/state in Germany. For example, in Berlin the murder rate per 100,000 people is 1.3, in Hamburg it is 0.9, etc etc...

I don't mind if it is murder or homicide as long as it is consistent across the dataset. It would also be better if the dataset includes other crimes such as thefts or assaults.

Answer (score 2):

Although this database doesn't specify per city/state, it contains information on crimes in Germany overall including homicide, kidnappings, robbery, assault - check out the [United Nations Office on Drugs and Crime](https://www.quandl.com/data/UNODC) database on Quandl. Search for "Germany" within the database to see the stats for Germany. Or, actually, you can also try this link directly: https://www.quandl.com/data/UNODC?keyword=germany

Hope this helps!

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]